# Not obtaining desired output

Tags: java

Basically, I have ask the user to input two exam scores (which are doubles). If the two exam scores average out to more than 90, then a message is outputted on the screen that they got an A, and so on for other average scores.

No matter what combination I enter, it always outputs that the user has obtained a 'C' grade even though they did not.

What is the issue here?

There were no compiler errors.

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;

class test3 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner zino = new Scanner(System.in);

    double score1 = 0;
    double score2 = 0;
    double average = 0;

    average = (score1 + score2) / 2 ;

    System.out.println("Enter score 1 ");
     score1 = zino.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter score 2 ");
     score2 = zino.nextDouble();

    if(average > 90)
    {
        System.out.println(average);
        System.out.println("You got an A!");
    }

    else if(average > 80)
    {
        System.out.println(average);
        System.out.println("You got a B.");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println(average);
        System.out.println("You got a C.");
    }`
}

}
```

If the user inputs two scores that are both 100, the output should be:

100
You got an A!

This is what I am getting:

0.0
You got a C.

Comment: You never modify the `average` variable so it is always zero. (You say its equal to `score1 + score2` (both of which are initialized to zero) divided by two

Comment: `average = (score1 + score2) / 2 ;` equates to `average = (0 + 0) / 2` ... maybe you should prompt the user for the scores BEFORE you calculate the average

Comment: This line's `average = (score1 + score2) / 2 ;` place is right before the if statement.

Comment: I recommend you learn to use a debugger to step through your code to see what is going on. It'll be very helpful in your programming career and save you a lot of time and headaches

Comment: average before if statement. got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Place the code  average=(score1+score 3)/2;  after you finished getting user inputs.

Your code should looks like this :

```
 System.out.println("Enter score 1 ");
 score1 = zino.nextDouble();

 System.out.println("Enter score 2 ");
 score2 = zino.nextDouble();

 average=(score1+score 3)/2;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you're calculating the average *before* you're reading the values of the two scores.

```
average = (score1 + score2) / 2 ;
```

When you run this line, `score1` and `score2` are both zero, so you're setting `average` to `( 0 + 0 ) / 2`, which of course is zero.

Later in your program, you have

```
score1 = zino.nextDouble();
...
score2 = zino.nextDouble();
```

which sets `score1` and `score2` to the values entered by the user.  But you never calculate `average` again - so it stays at zero.

What you need to do is move the line `average = (score1 + score2) / 2;` *downwards*, so that it runs *after* the two lines that set `score1` and `score2`.